# Looker Studio suddenly experiencing issues with aggregated metrics on Charts

Tags: sql, looker-studio

Currently working on a dashboard chart with several aggregated metrics. It was working fine until today, when the charts suddenly are showing system error. No changes have been made to the chart or data source.

Below is the stacktrace:

com.google.analytics.lego.web.server.domain.common.exception.InternalException: errorId: [ 8385910e ], Message: [ Backend error:[;;Response status error: 3
Backend error message: Column definitions have different aggregation types: t0.D1254103759105824158: SUM vs AUTO
Backend error status:
Backend Request Id: 2b38a81f-311185-20231213;] ]
at com.google.analytics.lego.web.server.infrastructure.backends.legoservice.LegoServiceExceptionHandler.getExceptionFromCanonicalError(LegoServiceExceptionHandler.java:931)
at com.google.analytics.lego.web.server.infrastructure.backends.legoservice.LegoServiceExceptionHandler.maybeThrowException(LegoServiceExceptionHandler.java:184)
at com.google.analytics.lego.web.server.domain.api.datasource.HandleLegoServiceResponseError.lambda$throwExceptionOnError$0(HandleLegoServiceResponseError.java:46)
at com.google.async.promisegraph.Promise.lambda$thenConsume$5(Promise.java:662)
at com.google.async.promisegraph.ThenPromise.lambda$buildResultFromInputs$0(ThenPromise.java:91)
at com.google.async.promisegraph.PromiseResult.fromSupplier(PromiseResult.java:29)
at com.google.async.promisegraph.ThenPromise.buildResultFromInputs(ThenPromise.java:87)
at com.google.async.promisegraph.AbstractPromise.complete(AbstractPromise.java:222)
at com.google.async.promisegraph.GraphEnvironment.pumpLoop(GraphEnvironment.java:322)
at com.google.async.promisegraph.GraphEnvironment.pumpWithoutBlocking(GraphEnvironment.java:254)
at com.google.async.promisegraph.BackgroundPump$Worker.run(BackgroundPump.java:158)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at com.google.apps.framework.server.AbstractThreadPoolModule$InitializingThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0(AbstractThreadPoolModule.java:424)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I tried reverting to previous versions still produced the same problem.  I tried removing the aggregated metric that was causing this issue, but it didn't work. A little lost on what might be causing the issue.